# AWS Glue (or Athena or Presto) - Changing Decimal Format

Tags: hive, presto, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I am trying to read a CSV file using Athena. One of the fields is a DOUBLE with comma as decimal separator instead of dot.

Is there a way to read it? Or Is the only way is to convert (using replace comma per dot) ?

Comment: AFAICT CSV files are read as `varchar` columns, so the question is how to parse a text like `'123,45'` into a `double` in SQL, right? If this is the case then I think the best you can get is `CAST(replace(text, ',', '.') AS double)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change a setting to make Athena read the values as doubles, but there are ways around it. You will have to use `string` as the data type of the column in both cases:

- Create a view that converts the value to doubles (using `CAST(replace(text, ',', '.') AS double)` as Piotr suggests). This way you don't have to include the conversion expression in every query.
- Use [CREATE TABLE AS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html) (CTAS) and convert the values to doubles (using the same expression) into a new table. If you do this you can also convert to for example Parquet and get other benefits too. It will have to be done each time the data changes, though, which might be inconvenient.